# Stored Procedure Order By Latest Date

Tags: datetime, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

How to order DateTime by latest?

Example:

```
WHERE last_read BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
ORDER BY
```

I am new to sql query, couldn't really understand the online explanation.
Sorry and thanks

Answer (score 1):

You order by column_name then add DESC to order by last to first, so in your case (assuming the date is in last_read)

```
ORDER BY last_read DESC
```